# How can a current version of Linphone be installed?

Tags: 16.04, ppa, linphone

I want to install a current version of Linphone. I have attempted to install using the following procedure on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linphone/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linphone
```

This installs only version 3.6.1 (the current version is 3.9.1). I have attempted to install a more current version using the following procedure:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rayanayar/linphone
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linphone
```

However, when this installation of Linphone is run, the following error is encountered:

```
linphone: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblinphone.so.8: undefined symbol: belle_sip_stack_set_http_proxy_host
```

So, how can a current version of Linphone be installed?

Comment: How about compiling it from source? You can pint me to the source and i write up an answer regarding it.

Comment: @Videonauth Hey there! I'd very much appreciate it if you could take a look. The source is available here: http://www.linphone.org/downloads-for-desktop.html I've attempted it myself but have run into difficulties ensuring dependencies are available.

Comment: Well got it compiling, check my answer below.

Comment: @d3pd I want to install flexisip on ubuntu 18 and build linphone android and ios apps. I searched a lot but did not find any complete and easy to follow solution. Then I found this https://ficus.myvnc.com/en/blog/SIP%20Server%20Flexisip%20Build%20and%20Install_b85 It is using docker. I wanted to ask if there is any other guide available. I am not a techie, but I can follow guides.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To compile from source you need to install first the following packages as dependencies (be carefull to select the whole box and paste it into terminal):

```bsh
sudo apt-get install git build-essential automake autoconf libtool   \
intltool libgtk2.0-dev libspeexdsp-dev libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev \
libx11-dev libxv-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libreadline-dev libgsm1-dev     \
libtheora-dev libsqlite3-dev libupnp-dev libsrtp-dev open-vm-tools   \
open-vm-tools-dev cmak* libmbedtls-dev libmbedtls-doc libmbedtls10   \
libcunit1 libcunit1-dev libantlr3c-dev libantlr3-runtime-java antlr3 \
libortp-dev libortp9 libmediastreamer-base3 libmediastreamer-dev     \
extra-cmake-modules yasm
```

For **Ubuntu 18.04** you need the following packages as well:

```bsh
python-pystache libv4l-dev libpulse-dev libglew-dev doxygen libbsd-dev \
qt5-default qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev \
libqt5texttospeech5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools \
qtquickcontrols2-5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2 \
qml-module-qtquick-dialogs  qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-templates2 \
qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings \ 
qml-module-qt-labs-platform
```

Now you can compile and install by doing the following steps:

```bsh
git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-desktop.git
cd linphone-desktop
git submodule sync && git submodule update --init --recursive
./prepare.py
make
sudo make install
```

Happy building. Please let me know if this worked for you on my system it builds but I don't want to install it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for taking the time to get this compile working. That works for me too on 16.04. That `git submodule` command is great. Thanks!

Comment: I also had to install the python2 version of pystache as well as the apt binaries for doxygen and graphviz.

Comment: @videonauth I want to install flexisip on ubuntu 18 and build linphone android and ios apps. I searched a lot but did not find any complete and easy to follow solution. Then I found this https://ficus.myvnc.com/en/blog/SIP%20Server%20Flexisip%20Build%20and%20Install_b85 It is using docker. I wanted to ask if there is any other guide available. I am not a techie, but I can follow guides.

Answer (score 5):

As I cannot comment I'll add this as another answer:

I tried the accepted answer today (on xubuntu 16.04) and got the message

```
Could not find a support sound driver API
```

I fixed this by installing libasound2-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

To get rid of some other warnings I installed some more packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev libvpx-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Also the make target install does not seem to exist anymore.

But linphone can be run directly from the output directory

```
OUTPUT/desktop/bin/linphone
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

**Worked on 16.04**

Must be root

```
sudo su
```

Install flatpak (It will compile everything for you)

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Install Linphone using flatpak

```
flatpak --user install --from https://linphone.org/flatpak/linphone.flatpakref
```

Comment: I tried this method, but I get:  The application com.belledonnecommunications.linphone/x86_64/4.1.1 requires the runtime org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.6 which was not found. How do I install the freedesktop thingy?

Comment: I could verify, that this works with Ubuntu 18.04, although I got no entry in the start menu, I had to use `flatpak list` and `flatpak run` to start the application and to add a menu entry.

Comment: Flatpak support [has been deprecated](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-desktop/issues/10#note_19743) in favor of AppImage

Answer (score 4):

In June 2017, Linphone Desktop 4 was released. With that, its authors Belledonne Communications changed from GTK+ 2 to Qt 5.9 LTS (to be more precise: They changed to QML with Qt Quick Controls 2). Furthermore, they added the [possibility](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone?qt-technical_corner=2) to download a ready-to-use binary via [Flatpak](http://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/). Therefore, although the previous answers were correct at their time, they changed:

### a) Download from Flatpak

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak --user install --from https://linphone.org/flatpak/linphone.flatpakref
flatpak run com.belledonnecommunications.linphone --verbose
```

---

### b) Build from Source

- to go for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and/or
- to debug/contribute to Linphone because you are a developer, and/or
- to enjoy the latest features and bug fixes, and/or
- to get more video and audio codecs.

The variant via Flatpak gives you as video codec just VP8. If you build yourself, MP4V-ES, H.263, and H.264 get added. As audio codecs, AMR, AMR-WB, iLBC, iSAC, and SiLK get added. Furthermore optionally, you can add even G.726 and Codec 2. However as of today, those two modules need to be patched to work with other VoIP/SIP implementations (wrong endianness and wrong bitrate).

To compile yourself, you need the Qt Framework. Therefore, you
a) go for the Qt Installer, *or*
b) go for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and its existing Qt 5.9 packages.

**Step 1a: Qt Installer**

```
wget download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
chmod u+x ./qt-unified-linux-*.run
./qt-unified-linux-*.run
```

In the Installer, you go for Qt → Qt 5.9.x → Desktop. When you set the `PATH` and `Qt5_DIR`, make sure it matches the version you downloaded:

```
Qt5_DIR="~/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/lib/cmake"
PATH="~/Qt/5.9.9/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH"
```

**Step 1b: Qt Packages**

```
sudo apt install qt5-default qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev libqt5texttospeech5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtquickcontrols2-5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtqml-models2 qml-module-qtquick-templates2 qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qt-labs-platform
```

As noted above, this works only with the latest Ubuntu. For older Ubuntu releases, I would go for the Qt Installer as described in alternative A. Furthermore, comments in the source code [indicate](http://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop/commit/5dd0161a68db97dd1bb1c367630821e61eae3584#diff-0c256a3e42505185ffbf734247b17e22), that Belledonne Communications is not sticking to long-term-support (LTS) releases but is going require the next stable release, when one after next stable branch was released (for example, when Qt 5.11 is released, Linphone might require Qt 5.10 already). Therefore, when you read this answer, this alternative B might already be no option anymore.

**Step 2 for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

```
sudo apt install autoconf libasound2-dev build-essential libbsd-dev cmake3 curl doxygen git libglew-dev graphviz libtool default-jre-headless nasm libpcap-dev pkg-config python-pystache python-six libudev-dev libwww-perl libxv-dev yasm libpolarssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev libsrtp0-dev libgsm1-dev libopus-dev libspeexdsp-dev libavcodec-extra libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libvpx-dev libantlr3c-dev antlr3 xsdcxx libxerces-c-dev libspandsp-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libvo-amrwbenc-dev
```

**Step 2 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

```
sudo apt install autoconf libasound2-dev build-essential libbsd-dev cmake curl doxygen git libglew-dev graphviz libtool default-jre-headless nasm libpcap-dev pkg-config python3-distutils python3-pystache python3-six libudev-dev libwww-perl libxv-dev yasm libmbedtls-dev libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev libsrtp0-dev libgsm1-dev libopus-dev libspeexdsp-dev libavcodec-extra libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libvpx-dev libantlr3c-dev antlr3 xsdcxx libxerces-c-dev libspandsp-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libvo-amrwbenc-dev libcodec2-dev
```

**Step 2 for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

```
sudo apt install autoconf libasound2-dev build-essential libbsd-dev cmake curl doxygen git libglew-dev graphviz libtool default-jre-headless nasm libpcap-dev pkg-config python3-distutils python3-pystache python3-six libturbojpeg0-dev libudev-dev libwww-perl libxv-dev yasm libmbedtls-dev libsqlite3-dev libxml2-dev libsrtp2-dev libgsm1-dev libopus-dev libspeexdsp-dev libavcodec-extra libavcodec-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libvpx-dev libantlr3c-dev antlr3 xsdcxx libxerces-c-dev libspandsp-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libvo-amrwbenc-dev libcodec2-dev
```

**Step 3**

```
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-desktop --recursive
cd ./linphone-desktop
python3 prepare.py --use-system-dependencies --all-codecs --debug --list-cmake-variables -DENABLE_AMRWB=OFF -DENABLE_AMR=OFF -DENABLE_UNMAINTAINED=ON -DENABLE_JPEG=OFF
make
gdb ./OUTPUT/desktop/bin/linphone -ex 'run --verbose'
```

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, you go for `python2`. In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, you can remove the `-DENABLE_JPEG=OFF`. In Ubuntu 19.10, you have to [patch a header file](https://github.com/sustrik/libdill/pull/197/files). As of today, several bugs are in the AMR(-WB) implementation; therefore it is disabled here.

---

Side note: Please, double-check the value of `quality_reporting_enabled` in the file `~/.config/linphone/linphonerc` whether it reflects your data-collection and privacy interests. For me, an `0` disabled the telemetry data which was send to Belledonne Communications after each call. Yet, I found no way to change that value via the graphical user-interface.

Comment: sounds good. Unfortunately this did not work for me on 18.04: The usual "recipe for target 'all' failed" as always with Linphone Desktop.

/cmake'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/linphone-desktop/WORK/desktop/cmake'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'desktop-build' failed
make: *** [desktop-build] Error 2

Comment: @opinion_no9 you are lucky: Yesterday, I had to re-build the latest Linphone on a vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation. However, it was made without any issue. (1) Which cmake-builder failed exactly – the main one? (2) Did cmake produce a file called `CMakeOutput.log`for that failed builder?
I see that you try to compile in `/usr/local/src`. I have not tried that yet but did everything in the home folder of a normal user. (3) Did you try to build in your normal `Documents` folder already?

Comment: @AlexanderTraud I tried the flatpack method but I get " The application com.belledonnecommunications.linphone/x86_64/4.1.1 requires the runtime org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.6 which was not found" What is this freedesktop thing?

Comment: @OldGeezer which version of Ubuntu do you use? Normally, the runtime Freedesktop is installed/available via Flathub. Previously, Flathub was added automatically. However, Flatpak changed their instructions (which I updated/added above). Therefore: Are you able to add Flathub? Is Freedesktop found now? If not, which version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: I am on 18.04. I finally managed to install by following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=51&v=2FM-wq6gPpA, which is performing an extra step before using `apt-get install linphone`. I am confused why there are so many different methods.

Comment: @AlexanderTraud I want to install flexisip on ubuntu 18 and build linphone android and ios apps. I searched a lot but did not find any complete and easy to follow solution. Then I found this https://ficus.myvnc.com/en/blog/SIP%20Server%20Flexisip%20Build%20and%20Install_b85 It is using docker. I wanted to ask if there is any other guide available. I am not a techie, but I can follow guides.

Comment: @Umair For Flexisip, I recommend to create a new question on Stack Exchange, because this one here is about Linphone for Ubuntu. The same for _each_ mobile platform, create a new question. Then, you are able to consider a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Beside that, Belledonne Communications offers consulting services.

Comment: @AlexanderTraud Question created https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206313/how-to-install-flexisip-server-and-build-linphone-android-app

Comment: @AlexanderTraud bounty hunter

Comment: Flatpak support [has been deprecated](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-desktop/issues/10#note_19743) in favor of AppImage

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Alexander TRAUD for his howTo without which I would not even have tried.

I still have to add the `XercesC` library and everything has compiled on Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
apt install libxerces-c-dev
./prepare.py -c
./prepare.py --use-system-dependencies --all -codes --debug --list-cmake-variables -DENABLE_JPEG = OFF -DENABLE_DOC = OFF
make
```

This should do the job.