# How to install flexisip server and build linphone android app

Tags: android, linphone

I want to install flexisip on ubuntu 18 Bionic and build linphone android and ios apps. The official docs are for centos 7 and debian 9 and are not very explanatory. I searched a lot but did not find any complete and easy to follow solution. Then I found this https://ficus.myvnc.com/en/blog/SIP%20Server%20Flexisip%20Build%20and%20Install_b85 It is the most easiet and detailed I have found so far. It is using docker. I am not sure if it is the right guide to follow. I wanted to ask if there is any other guide available. I am not a techie, but I can follow guides. I have a free account on aws. I use putty to access ssh terminal.

Moreover, if someone can add a step for generating letsencrypt. That would be a plus.

I am running windows 10 on my laptop.

Comment: You must follow a sequence of steps (install Ubuntu on AWS, download source, compile source, etc.) and it's not clear which step you are stuck on. Are you simply unfamiliar with how to compile source code? Or are you asking us to detail that entire sequence of steps? Or something else?

Comment: @user535733 ubuntu is already installed. Domain is setup as well on aws. I am unfamiliar with compiling source. I need detailed steps.

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source for instructions on how to compile source code. Advice: Try some small and simple "hello world" code first to make all the first-time mistakes upon, then work your way up.

Comment: As only debian and centos are officially supported. May be it is wiser to install on debian 9. If anyone answers, please answer for debian 9.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://ficus.myvnc.com/en/blog/SIP%20Server%20Flexisip%20Build%20and%20Install_b85) ? I've built linphone some weeks ago on 18.04 - I can send you some infos on Monday (I can't access them until then)

Comment: @RobertRiedl I have mentioned it in question.

Comment: oops, sorry. The offical Doc for linphone is not LinuxOS specific [see here](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-desktop). I can provide you with more info, come Monday.

Comment: Hi @Umair sorry for the delay. With the instructions of [this link here](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop/issues/140#issuecomment-386990449) I was able to build linphone on 18.04. I hope this helps.

Comment: @RobertRiedl The link you shared is for building linphone on ubuntu. Please read my question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to build linphone for ubuntu - since this is an ubuntu site. You might have more luck with your question on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RobertRiedl ok thanks. no problem. If I integrate liblinphone in my existing app, do I need a voip server to make audio video calls?

Comment: You don't need the voipserver to make calls, if you have another voipserver somewhere to use. Only one voipsever is needed to make SIP calls for all participants, not one per participant.